# Same javascript function on multiple Elements, only last one triggers | special explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, triggers

Details: 

Situation = first own js function still not working,

english skill = terrible,

explanation = following code,

problem = only last call of function "fnElementVisible" works,

goal = understand my (thinking) errors;

Code for explanation:

```js
$(function() {
  var
  $document = $(document),
  _windowSize = $(window).outerHeight();
  
 $.fn.extend({
  fnElementVisible: function(_value){ //_value = the position in % when the elem should has an opacity=1
   $self = $(this),
   $selfOffset = $self.offset(),
   _selfHeight = $self.outerHeight();

   $document.on('scroll', function(){
    if($selfOffset.top - _windowSize <= $document.scrollTop() && $selfOffset.top + _selfHeight >= $document.scrollTop()){ //check if element is in the visible area of the window
     $self.css({
      background: 'rgba(0,0,0,' + (($document.scrollTop()-($selfOffset.top-_windowSize))/(_windowSize*(_value/100)))+ ')'
     })
    }
   })
  }
 })


  $('#item-1').fnElementVisible(60); //ignored
  $('#item-2').fnElementVisible(70); //ignored
  $('#item-3').fnElementVisible(80); //ignored
  $('#item-4').fnElementVisible(90); //ignored
  $('#item-5').fnElementVisible(100);
})
```

```css
/*unimportant*/
body{
margin: 0;
}
.spacer{
 height: 430px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: lightgray;
 }
 
 .item{
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: 2%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="spacer">spacer</div>
    <p id="item-1" class="item">elem1</p>
    <p id="item-2" class="item">elem2</p>
    <p id="item-3" class="item">elem3</p>
    <p id="item-4" class="item">elem4</p>
    <p id="item-5" class="item">elem5</p>
<div class="spacer">spacer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using undeclared variables when you write

```
$self = $(this),
  $selfOffset = $self.offset(),
  _selfHeight = $self.outerHeight();
```

Those variables are global, not in the scope of your function. This causes the observed effect. So you simply prepend a `let` or `var` declaration to your variables, i.e.:

```
let $self = $(this),
  $selfOffset = $self.offset(),
  _selfHeight = $self.outerHeight();
```

Comment: such a dumb mistake. this is the solution. **thank you very much**